Can't git clone git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
I upgraded my laptop from Jammy to Noble yesterday and was redoing my SSH keys for github. I created a new ssh key, added it with ssh-add, and follows all the steps on the github website.
I am getting the correct output as shown below
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi MokshC! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I also used ssh-add -l -E md5 and it worked as expected. But I am still getting the below error.
$ sudo git clone git@github.com:MokshC/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Any tips on what I could try?
EDIT: not using sudo results in the error fatal: could not create work tree dir 'repo': Permission denied

Why are you using sudo here? that is likely looking for your key in the wrong place

When I don't use sudo I get this error fatal: could not create work tree dir 'repo': Permission denied

So likely the first time you tried to run it with sudo, that created a root-owned subdirectory that you will need to chown or remove before you can clone as an unprivileged user

you're absolutely correct, thank you!

Turns out the permissions of the folder I was attempting to clone into were locked, so I was using sudo causing ubuntu to look for the key in the wrong place. I simply did a sudo chmod 777 on the working folder, then ran git clone without the sudo and it worked.

Changing permissions to 777 is not a good solution at all, it makes little sense and the folder is still owned by root. You should sudo rm -rf the root-owned folder and then just recreate the repo's base folder by cloning again without sudo.

Thank you for the advice, I did that just now and all worked smoothly. Can you give me some more details on why using 777 is not a good solution other than it still being owned by root?

I apologize for I have miswrote in previous comment, I meant: the very first that comes to mind: nasty user "Fred" logs in and decides to delete the contents of the folder. You haven't pushed to the remote repo in a week and your work is gone. There are more reasons, that go beyond what I can explain in a comment, in general you should strive to give files / folders just the bare permissions they require to function for your purpose. I suggest you read this, which is authoritative and informative enough: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-file-permissions-explained
